# Request io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl was not original or a wrapper

Tags: rest, wildfly, undertow

I try to forward the request to a JSP page from a Rest method in WildFly 8.1 but this throws an Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010023: Request io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl@88ad706 was not original or a wrapper
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:103) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at my.domain.RestResource.myRestMethod(RestResource.java:525) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    ... 31 more
```

The code:

```
@GET
@Path("/my-path")
public void myRestMethod(@Context final HttpServletResponse response,
        @Context final HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException {

     RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/path/to/jsp");
     dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

This code worked without problems in Jboss 7.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did not debug enough to understand why/when those checks have been added (apparently this is required by the Servlet specification), but there is an option in Undertow to disable it:

In the `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` file change the `servlet-container` XML element so that it has the attribute `allow-non-standard-wrappers="true"`.

For details, check [the official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Undertow%20subsystem%20configuration.html) (the `Servlet container configuration` section).